# How to include other HTML files as module in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have a template file called `main.html` and I want to add my navbar in `nav.html` to my `main.html`. How can I do that in tornado? I looked in [tornado documents](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html) where they recommended to use

```
{% module Template("module-entry.html", show_comments=True) %}
```

However when I tried to add my module as

```
 {% module Template("nav.html") %}
```

I got `FileNotFoundException`

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/sigma/PycharmProjects/tornadoProj/__/views/nav.html'

I don't understand how `__` gets in my path? Help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not use module,you can use ***block*** in **main.html** you can like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        {% block header %}{% end %}
    </header>
    <content>
        {% block body %}{% end %}
    </content>
    <footer>
        {% block footer %}{% end %}
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In nav.html:

```
{% block header %}
    <ul><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul>
{% end %}
```